# Animar um menu lateral em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá, estou entrando agora no mundo WPF (venho do MVC), e estou com uma dúvida: Eu estou tentando animar um menu expansível, ou seja, quando o usuário clicar no botão, ele expande e quando clica novamente ele esconde.

Eu até consegui realizar a animação, porem quando o menu expansível aparece, ele empurra o componente que está situado ao lado do mesmo.

Minha dúvida é: Como animar um DockPanel sem "empurrar" o do lado, se usarmos termos da web, minha dúvida é se tem como deixar um DockPanel como "absolute"?

Abaixo segue o XAML eas Prints:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbShowMenu">
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="-150,43,0,0" To="0,43,0,0" DecelerationRatio="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="sbHideMenu">
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0,43,0,0" To="-150,43,0,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel1">
    <!--Inicio BarraTitulo-->
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#FF26A896" Height="30px">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="12px" Foreground="#fff" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                App Teste
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="CloseButton" Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" Click="CloseButton_Click">
                <Image Source="Imgs/icons/Delete_64px.png" Margin="5" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    <!--Fim BarraTitulo-->

    <!--Inicio Menu-->
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="43" Background="#FF222222" Name="Nav" Height="Auto" Panel.ZIndex="2">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Background="#FF26A896" BorderThickness="0" Click="BtnToggleMenu_Click" Name="BtnToggleMenu">
                <Image Source="Imgs/icons/Menu_100px.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10" />
            </Button>
            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                <Image Source="Imgs/icons/Home_64px.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                <Image  Stretch="Fill" Margin="10" Source="Settings_64px.png" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    <!--Fim Menu-->

    <!--Inicio Menu Expansivel-->
    <DockPanel Name="NavExt" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="-150,43,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Background="#222" Width="150">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Vertical" >
            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Height="43" Foreground="#fff" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="15,0,0,0" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="14">
                Pagina Inicial
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Height="43" Foreground="#fff" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="15,0,0,0" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="14">
                Configurações
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    <!--Fim Menu Expansivel-->

    <!--Inicio MainContainer-->
    <DockPanel Panel.ZIndex="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="MainContainer">
        <StackPanel x:Name="dockPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="86" Background="#FFF" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Border Height="43">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuTitle}" >
                    Pagina Inicial
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>

            <StackPanel Height="43" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Padding="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuItens}">
                    Operações
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubMenuItens}">
                    Estatísticas
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <UserControl Name="MainContent"></UserControl>
    </DockPanel>
    <!--Fim MainContainer-->

</DockPanel>
```

[image: Menu Expandido]
[image: Menu Escondido]

[image: Gif]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O DockPanel não tem a propriedade ZIndex, que te permitiria definir o índice de relevância (não consegui pensar em outra forma de explicar) do componente no layout, bem igualzinho a web.

Substitua o DockPanel por uma Grid, por exemplo, e utilize o ZIndex pra definir a relevância do seu menu sobre os demais elementos.

Comment: Consegui fazer o que queria fazendo o uso de grid com colunas. Porem, o que disse sobre o ZIndex não funcionar no DockPanel, ele funciona normalmente como em outros tipos de layout, e como você disse, realmente é igual a web.